# How do I set the class of a variable using pipes?

Tags: r, class, tidyverse, tibble, openxlsx

I have create a function that builds a tibble from a few basic inputs

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
fun <- function(x, y) {
  tibble(
    start = x) %>%
  mutate(k = x * y)
}
```

What I would like to do is set the `class` of each variable within this function.

```
fun <- function(x, y) {
  tibble(
    start = x) %>%
  mutate(k = x * y) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(x, k), "currency")
}
```

I've tried

```
fun <- function(x, y) {
  tibble(
    start = x) %>%
  mutate(k = x * y) %>%
  class(k) <- "currency"
}
```

My goal is to create a tibble that includes classes in them for later export using the `openxlsx` package.  I've found lots of ways to convert from factors to numeric, etc. using the mutate_at function, but cannot find a way to define the class of a tibble (or data frame) variable in the same function it is create.  I know I can do this in a script easy enough, but it seems like something I should be able to do within a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the `"currency"` class from? The closest I could find was `formattable::currency` (even that returns class `"formattable" "numeric"`) . In which case, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(x, y) {

  tibble(start = x) %>%
    mutate(k = x * y) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(start, k), formattable::currency)
}

fun(1:10, 2)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   start      k         
#   <formttbl> <formttbl>
# 1 $1.00      $2.00     
# 2 $2.00      $4.00     
# 3 $3.00      $6.00     
# 4 $4.00      $8.00     
# 5 $5.00      $10.00    
# 6 $6.00      $12.00    
# 7 $7.00      $14.00    
# 8 $8.00      $16.00    
# 9 $9.00      $18.00    
#10 $10.00     $20.00
```

Even if it is from some different package you would be able to do the same with the default methods present in the class. For example, to change it to `"character"` class you could use :

```
fun <- function(x, y) {
   tibble(start = x) %>%
     mutate(k = x * y) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(start, k), as.character)
}
```

---

**EDIT**

```
fun <- function(x, y) {

  data <- tibble(start = x) %>% mutate(k = x * y)
  data[c('k', 'start')] <- lapply(data[c('k', 'start')], 
                             function(x) {class(x) <- "Currency";x})
   return(data)
}

str(fun(1:10, 2))
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ start: 'Currency' int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ k    : 'Currency' num  2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Comment: The "currency" class is coming from `openxlsx` package

Comment: I tried adding: `mutate_at(vars(start, k), openxlsx::currency)` but it is say "Error: 'currency' is not an exported object from 'namespace:openxlsx'"

Comment: is there an alternative way to set a class for multiple objects in a data frame?  `class(vars(df$start, k)) <- "currency"`

Comment: Thank you Ronak. I’ve gotten so used to Tidyverse, forgot to use old school skills. I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you want to stay in `tidyverse`, you can change `lapply` to `map` and this would work the same.

Comment: I will have to read up on ‘map’. I’ve never been very good with the various apply functions. A lot of brute force scripting is my usual method. Tidyverse has made entry into learning  R much easier. I think it is time for me to study up on map. Thanks again Ronak. I really appreciate the help.